# Sublime Text Automatically Adding Forgotten Braces

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sometimes, I want to change the body in a for-loop from one line to multiple lines. In Sublime Text the process goes like this for me:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println("Hello World");
```

And then I try to insert the curly braces by typing in the open brace (which automatically types the closing brace)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){}
    System.out.println("Hello World");
```

I see that for some other people, the curly braces are inserted correctly. Namely, the closing brace will be at the end of the body.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

No changes were made in their settings and it has always been like that for them. I transitioned from Sublime Text 2 to 3, and I never had that behavior in either version. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I think a more suitable place for this question is on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), it is more like mastering the software than a real programming question.

Comment: which version are you using? On my CentOS with sublime text 3 (version 3143), inserting curly braces way what you desired works fine.

Comment: I'm using OSX with sublime text 3 (version 3143) as well.

Comment: Remove all your User Settings and any relevant Syntax specific settings so you are running the out-of-the-box Default settings. Test. If that does not highlight the issue as being in settings uninstall all installed packages. Test. If it is a package causing the issue add them back one at a time until you encounter the problem and you have found the problem package.